# R Webscraping from WFP website

Tags: r, database, keyword

I am using WFP country website (http://www1.wfp.org/countries) aiming web scraping it in order to build up a dataset containing the news issued periodically on that without clicking each time page after page.
Furthermore, I would add some columns including keyword count.
Leaving aside the part of the script containing the Countries and the urls I would focus on the scraping itself, indeed.
Yet, I am using a bunch of packages.

`library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
library(xml2)
library(selectr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(datapasta)
library(jsonlite)
library(countrycode)
library(httr)
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(XML)`

I have prepared the dataset for another website and it seems to work well.
A helper here suggested a quite elegant solution for the thing and I have integrated it with my previous work on the country part and everything works well in that. Nevertheless, the solution does not seem to comply with my present need.
Yet, I have this:

```
## 11. Creating a function in order to scrape data from a website (in this case, WFP's)
wfp_get_news <- function(iso3) {                                                          GET(
url = "http://www1.wfp.org/countries/common/allnews/en/",
query = list(iso3=iso3)
) -> res

warn_for_status(res)

if (status_code(res) > 399) return(NULL)

out <- content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8")
out <- jsonlite::fromJSON(out)
out$iso3 <- iso3

tbl_df(out)
}




## 12. Setting all the Country urls in order for them to be automatically scraped 
pb <- progress_estimated(length(countrycode_data$iso3c[]))                                   # THIS TAKES LONG TO BE PROCESSED                         
map_df(countrycode_data$iso3c[], ~{
pb$tick()$print()
Sys.sleep(5) 
wfp_get_news(.x)
}) -> xdf



## 13. Setting keywords (of course, this process is arbitrary: one can    decide any keywor s/he prefers)
keywords <- c("drought", "food security")                                        


keyword_regex <- sprintf("(%s)", paste0(keywords, collapse="|"))




## 14. Setting the keywords search
bind_cols(                                                                                  
xdf,
stri_match_all_regex(tolower(xdf$bodytext), keyword_regex) %>% 
map(~.x[,2]) %>% 
map_df(~{ 
  res <- table(.x, useNA="always")
  nm <- names(res)
  nm <- ifelse(is.na(nm), "NONE", stri_replace_all_regex(nm, "[ -]", "_"))
  as.list(set_names(as.numeric(res), nm))
 })
 ) %>% 
 select(-NONE) -> xdf_with_keyword_counts
```

In particular, when I run point 14. if the script, I attain the following error message:

```
Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : 
object "NONE" not found
Furthermore: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'bodytext'.
```

The expected result should be, more or less, instead:

```
> glimpse(xdf_with_keyword_counts)
  Observations: 12,375
  Variables: 12
  $ uid           <chr> "1071595", "1069933", "1069560", "1045264", "1044139", "1038339", "405003", "1052711", NA, "1062329", "1045248", "...
  $ table         <chr> "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", NA, "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", NA, "n...
  $ title         <chr> "Conflicts and drought spur hunger despite strong global food supply", "FAO Calls for Stronger Collaboration on Tr...
  $ date          <chr> "1512640800", "1511823600", "1511737200", "1508191200", "1508104800", "1505980800", "1459461600", "1293836400", NA...
  $ bodytext      <chr> " 7 December 2017, Rome- Strong cereal harvests are keeping global food supplies buoyant, but localised drought, f...
  $ date_format   <chr> "07/12/2017", "28/11/2017", "27/11/2017", "17/10/2017", "16/10/2017", "21/09/2017", "01/04/2016", "01/01/2011", NA...
  $ image         <chr> "http://www.wfp.org...", "http://www.wfp.org...
  $ pid           <chr> "2330", "50840", "16275", "70992", "16275", "2330", "40990", "40990", NA, "53724", "53724", "2330", "53724", "5084...
  $ detail_pid    <chr> "/news/story/en/item/1071595/icode/", "/neareast/news/view/en/c/1069933/", "/asiapacific/news/detail-events/en/c/1...
  $ iso3          <chr> "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "ALA", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "DZA", "ASM", "AND", "A...
  $ drought       <dbl> 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,...
  $ food_security <dbl> NA, NA, NA, 2, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,...
```

I hope I made myself quite clear.
Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you hit one of the "gotchas" in web scraping: they removed this functionality/paths on the web site.

Try going to http://www1.wfp.org/countries/common/allnews/en/iso=SLV (El Salvador's news page from the URL scheme you were using a cpl days ago). It doesn't exist.

But, if you go to http://www1.wfp.org/countries/el-salvador there's a link for http://www.wfp.org/news/el-salvador-177 on that page which is the El Salvador news items.

I think it's the same content, just presented differently, so it's just attacking it differently:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
```

This is a helper so we can get their country id's and name mappings:

```
get_countries <- function() {

  pg <- read_html("http://www.wfp.org/news/news-releases?tid=All&tid_2=All")

  # find the country popup
  country_sel <- html_nodes(pg, "select[name='tid'] option")

  # extract ids and name for each country, ignoring "All"
  data_frame(
    cid = html_attr(country_sel, "value"),
    cname = html_text(country_sel)
  ) %>%
    filter(stri_detect_regex(cid, "[[:digit:]]"))

}
```

This is a helper to get the news content on a page

```
get_news <- function(cid, tid) {

  GET("http://www.wfp.org/news/news-releases",
      query=list(tid=cid, tid_2=tid)) -> res

  warn_for_status(res)

  if (status_code(res) > 200) return(NULL)

  res <- content(res, as="parsed")

  # check for no stories by testing for the presence of the
  # div that has the "no stories are found" text
  if (length(html_node(res, "div.view-empty")) != 0) return(NULL)

  # find the news item boxes on this page
  items <- html_nodes(res, "div.list-page-item")

  # extract the contents
  data_frame(
    cid = cid,
    tid = tid,
    # significant inconsistency in how they assign CSS classes to date boxes
    date = html_text(html_nodes(items, xpath=".//div[contains(@class, 'box-date')]"), trim=TRUE),
    title = html_text(html_nodes(items, "h3"), trim=TRUE),
    # how & where they put summary text in the div is also inconsistent so we
    # need to (unfortunately) include the date and title to ensure we capture it
    # we cld get just the text, but it's more complex code.
    summary = html_text(items, trim=TRUE),
    link = html_attr(html_nodes(items, "h3 a"), "href")
  )

}
```

Now, we iterate over the countries and get all the stories:

```
country_df <- get_countries()

pb <- progress_estimated(length(country_df$cid))
map_df(country_df$cid, ~{
  pb$tick()$print()
  get_news(.x, "All")
}) -> news_df

# add in country names
mutate(news_df, cid = as.character(cid)) %>%
  left_join(country_df) -> news_df

glimpse(news_df)
## Observations: 857
## Variables: 7
## $ cid     <chr> "120", "120", "120", "120", "120", "120", "120", "120", "120", "120"...
## $ tid     <chr> "All", "All", "All", "All", "All", "All", "All", "All", "All", "All"...
## $ date    <chr> "26 October 2017", "16 October 2017", "2 October 2017", "10 July 201...
## $ title   <chr> "US Contribution To Boost WFP Food Assistance And Local Economy In A...
## $ summary <chr> "26 October 2017\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\tUS Contribution To Boost WFP Food ...
## $ link    <chr> "/news/news-release/us-contribution-boost-wfp-food-assistance-and-lo...
## $ cname   <chr> "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghani...
```

You still need to try to classify this by adapting the other code you have, and you can use the `link` in the data frame to mine more text for said classification.

NOTE: this only gets the most recent news page for each country but that's pretty much what you want to do anyway (check for net-new & classify them).

---

Now, we can *try* to auto-classify stories by looping through country & pop-up topics list since those topics seem to be what you care about (some of them). You'll need to trust that they tagged things well.

NOTE: This is going to take a *long* time especially with the "being kind" delay hence why I only scaffold-ed it and didn't run it apart from a light test to ensure it worked:

```
# get topic ids
get_topics <- function() {

  pg <- read_html("http://www.wfp.org/news/news-releases?tid=All&tid_2=All")

  # find the topic popup
  country_sel <- html_nodes(pg, "select[name='tid_2'] option")

  # extract ids and name for each topic, ignoring "All" and sub-topics
  # i.e. ignore ones that begin with "-"
  data_frame(
    tid = html_attr(country_sel, "value"),
    tname = html_text(country_sel)
  ) %>%
    filter(stri_detect_regex(tid, "[[:digit:]]")) %>%
    filter(tid != "All") # exclude "All" since we're trying to auto-tag

}

topics_df <- get_topics()

pb <- progress_estimated(length(country_df$cid))
map_df(country_df$cid, ~{
  pb$tick()$print()
  cid <- .x
  Sys.sleep(5) ## NOTE THIS SHOULD REALLY GO IN get_news() but I didn't want to mess with that function for this extra part of the example
  map_df(topics_df$tid, ~get_news(cid, .x))
}) -> news_with_tagged_topics_df

mutate(news_with_tagged_topics_df, tid = as.character(tid), cid = as.character(cid)) %>% 
  left_join(topics_df) %>% 
  left_join(country_df) %>% 
  glimpse()
```

I ran it for a random sample of 3 countries:

```
## Observations: 11
## Variables: 8
## $ cid     <chr> "4790", "4790", "4790", "4790", "4790", "4790", "4790", "152", "152"...
## $ tid     <chr> "4488", "3929", "3929", "995", "999", "1005", "1005", "997", "995", ...
## $ date    <chr> "16 December 2014", "2 September 2016", "1 October 2014", "1 October...
## $ title   <chr> "Russia & WFP Seal Partnership To End Hunger; Kamaz Trucks Rolled Ou...
## $ summary <chr> "16 December 2014\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\tRussia & WFP Seal Partnership To ...
## $ link    <chr> "/news/news-release/russia-wfp-seal-partnership-end-hunger-kamaz-tru...
## $ tname   <chr> "Executive Director", "Centre of Excellence against Hunger", "Centre...
## $ cname   <chr> "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil"...
```

and it did pick up a diversity of tags:

```
unique(news_with_tagged_topics_df$tname)
## [1] "Executive Director"                  "Centre of Excellence against Hunger"
## [3] "Nutrition"                           "Procurement"                        
## [5] "School Meals"                        "Logistics"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful. 
I am going throught it and once I have run it I would let you know.

Comment: This has been very useful, thanks.
Any suggestion on how to include keywords count (please see above for details)?